# Лишние запятые

Tags: общие-вопросы

Попалась в интернете статья. Вот цитата: *"Многие лингвисты замечают: главная беда сейчас — это не орфографические ошибки и не путаница в ударениях, это лишние запятые. В прошлом году это подтвердила и акция «Тотальный диктант», где самыми распространенными ошибками были именно запятые «сверх нормы» в самых неожиданных местах"*.
Честно говоря, мне как-то слабо в это верится. Напротив, я наблюдаю практически полное отсутствие запятых.
А вы как считаете, прав ли автор статьи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парадокс в том, что обилие лишних запятых не восполняет их нехватку в нужных местах. Люди ставят запятые там, где делают паузы, а их можно сделать практически после каждого слова. Многие, например, ставят запятую после "то есть".

Answer (score 2):

Проблема лишних запятых напрямую связана с методикой обучения пунктуации. Практически все наши правила основаны на грамматическом принципе, об интонации вспоминают очень редко. Письменная речь существует как бы отдельно от устной,  соответственно, отсутствует понимание связи между паузами и запятыми.

Паузы же в речи встречаются часто: это и перелом интонации в простом предложении (нет запятой), это произносительные паузы в значительно распространенном предложении (нет запятой).  Запятыми же обозначаются паузы, подтвержденные грамматикой.

Поэтому "неправильные" запятые - это не "избыточная грамотность", а повод для лингвистов еще раз  задуматься о правильности обучающих методик, а не только удивляться и печалиться по поводу лишних знаков, с которыми непонятно как бороться.

Comment: >> об интонации вспоминают очень редко

И слава богу, и так уж число запятых во фразах типа "А ты, что сейчас делаешь?" зашкаливает.

>> отсутствует понимание связи между паузами и запятыми.

Опять же – слава богу. Потому что эта связь такая непрямая, такая витиеватая, такая *необязательная*, что её нужно либо изучать ооочень серьёзно, либо не рассматривать вовсе. А серединка на половинку – не получится.

Comment: В действительности она очень простая, элементарная и всем доступная (начиная с 5-го класса). А все страшилки основаны на том, что интонацию (очень сложную фонетическую структуру) не отличают от простых интонационных схем, состоящих из двух элементов: движение голоса верх-вниз и пауз различной длительности.

Comment: Полно случаев, когда пауза в речи есть, а знака препинания нет. Полно и обратных случаев. Десятками процентов исчисляются. А тогда зачем? Вы же яростная противница запутывания бедных школьников, а тут хотите запутать их так, что мама не горюй! Вот-с, детки, изволите ли видеть, есть синтаксис, но есть и интонация! И они, так уж получилось, в половине случаев не дружат между собой.

Comment: Во многих случаях мы имеем соответствие "пауза-запятая", что определяется единством интонационно-грамматического принципа. На периферии находятся: только интонационный принцип (например, авторское интонационное тире) и только грамматический принцип (в сложных конструкциях интонация соответствует старшей форме, и нет возможности обозначить паузами все входящие обособленные члены). И "бедным школьникам" очень несложно объяснить, что любое простое неосложненное предложение состоит из двух фраз, но пауза на переломе интонации не обозначается запятой. Пусть они внимательно послушают родную речь.

Comment: А зачем? Одного синтаксиса недостаточно? Синтаксис определяет пунктуацию процентов на 99, зачем подробно рассматривать интонацию? Это приведёт только к росту "лишних запятых".

Answer (score 1):

Полное отсутствие запятых тоже имеет место, но в основном в соцсетях. Вполне возможно автор статьи прав, говоря об избытке запятых в диктанте.

Answer (score 0):

Мои многолетние наблюдения показывают, что автор этой статьи абсолютно прав.

Answer (score 0):

Это так называемая "избыточная грамотность" или "гиперкоррекция". Действительно, лишних запятых гораздо больше, чем недостающих.

Comment: Я это называю "горе от ума")))